# Is there a way to re-organise the compressed javascript for readability

Tags: javascript, yui-compressor

Is there a way to re-organise the compressed javascript file for readability ?

Any tool or script that might help !

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org

Comment: SLaks' link is literally *the first result* when you Google `Is there a way to re-organise the compressed javascript for readability`. Please always remember to do that first.

Comment: my bad, i didnt google it until putting it here .... damn .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal preference is for: http://jsbeautifier.org/.

I've used it before to de-obfuscate some compressed Google JS.

Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921713/de-obfuscate-javascript-code-to-make-it-readable-again).