# what kind of encryption is this? javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, encryption

well i was reading some files i got my hands on and this javascript file had this array that jQuery inside this file is using.

what kind of encryption is this code?

```
var _0x75cc=["\x73\x6C\x6F\x77",
"\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x54\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65",
    "\x23\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74","\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B",
        "\x23\x6F\x70\x65\x6E","\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79",
            "\x68\x69\x64\x65",
                 "\x23\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x20\x3E\x20\x64\x69\x76\x3A\x67\x74\x28\x30\x29",
                    "\x23\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x73\x68\x6F\x77","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x54\x6F","\x65\x6E\x64",
                    "\x66\x61\x64\x65\x49\x6E","\x6E\x65\x78\x74","\x66\x61\x64\x65\x4F\x75\x74",
                        "\x23\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x20\x3E\x20\x64\x69\x76\x3A\x66\x69\x72\x73\x74",
                    "\x63\x6F\x70\x79","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64",
                "\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E",
```

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [De-obfuscate Javascript code to make it readable again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921713/de-obfuscate-javascript-code-to-make-it-readable-again)

Answer (score 4):

Hex/Oct. Try pasting it in: http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/

```
var _0x75cc = ["slow",
    "slideToggle",
    "#content", "click",
    "#open", "ready",
    "hide",
    "#slideshow > div:gt(0)",
    "#slideshow", "appendTo", "end",
    "fadeIn", "next", "fadeOut",
    "#slideshow > div:first",
    "copy", "getElementById",
    "location",
```